# Windows Listen to service Status Changed

Tags: c++, winapi, qt, service

How Can I make an app that listens to services for Service Status Changed event. (I don't want repeated checking on of all services)

**EDIT**

I need it to work on Windows XP / 2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`NotifyServiceStatusChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which requires Vista. On 2000/XP you will need to poll.

Comment: I am no looking for one Particular Service. rather I want to get notified whenever **any** service changes its status. and Its Windows Vista and above only. I need to get it for Windows XP and 2000

Comment: @Neel Enumerate all the services and call the function for each service.

Comment: Sorry for a late edit. I forgot to mention it on the question, I need it to work on Windows XP / 2000

Comment: @Neel You will have to poll for those operating systems.

Comment: Did you mean repeated checking on list of all services ?

Answer (score 1):

In Vista and above you can use `NotifyServiceStatusChange` API. See some [sample code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164252.aspx).

If you are monitoring more than one service, you will have to call `NotifyServiceStatusChange` for each service you want to have monitored.

Comment: Sorry for a late edit. I forgot to mention I need it to work on Windows XP / 2000

Answer (score -1):

You could use WMI with something like `SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Service'` and then checking the State field of the Win32_Service class.

Comment: Not really.  Granted you still have to query the object to gets its new state, but you receive the state change events [asychronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393011%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Doh, you are right.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390355%28v=VS.85%29.aspx): _WMI uses polling to detect the changes_.